# Higher-order functions in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to write a generic fold function using the new anonymous functions available in C++11, here is what I have:

```
template<typename T>
T foldl(std::function<T(T,T)> f, T initial, std::vector<T> items) {
    T accum = initial;
    for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it) {
        accum = f(accum, (*it));
    }
    return accum;
}
```

The following attempt to use it:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
arr.assign(8, 2);
foldl([] (int x, int y) -> int { return x * y; }, 1, arr);
```

causes an error:

```
main.cpp:44:61: error: no matching function for call to 'foldl(main(int, char**)::<lambda(int, int)>, int, std::vector<int>&)'
main.cpp:44:61: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:20:3: note: template<class T> T foldl(std::function<T(T, T)>, T, std::vector<T>)
main.cpp:20:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:44:61: note:   'main(int, char**)::<lambda(int, int)>' is not derived from 'std::function<T(T, T)>'
```

It seems to me that using `std::function` is not the right way to go about defining the type of `f`. How can I correct this?

Comment: Is there something wrong [with `std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Comment: I'm just playing around in C++ and wanted to write my own.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code is not very generic. There is no need to require a `function`, `vector`, or anything of the kind. And generally, in C++, functions would go at the end of the argument list (especially important for lambdas, as they can be big).

So it would be better (ie: more standard) to write this as this:

```
template<typename Range, typename Accum>
typename Range::value_type foldl(const Range &items, const typename Range::value_type &initial, Accum f)
{
    typename Range::value_type accum = initial;
    for(const auto &val : items) {
        accum = f(accum, val);
    }

    return accum;
}
```

Or you could just [use `std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) which does *the exact same thing*.

Comment: Could you explain why functions should be passed as the last argument? And lambdas are big? What? Isn't it just a function reference, like any other function passed like this?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: Lambdas are big in terms of what you have to type to create them. So having parameters after them in the parameter list looks odd at the call site.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain why this template is failing, but switching over to using a template parameter for the function instead of `std::function<>` seems to work wonderfully.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T foldl(F f, T initial, std::vector<T> items) {
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply convert it to an `std::function` first, and then use that, it will work:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
arr.assign(8, 2);
std::function<int(int,int)> f = [] (int x, int y) -> int { return x * y; };
foldl(f, 1, arr);
```

The problem is that lambda is a different type than `std::function`. Each lambda is a separate type. Although a lambda (and all other function objects) is convertible to a `std::function` with appropriate type parameter, the compiler has no idea what template argument for `T` would make it convertible. (We happen to know that `T` = `int` would work, but there is no general way to figure it out.) So it cannot compile it.

Comment: So, are most compilers just lacking the ability to infer that the type `T` must be `int`? Because I don't really see why else there would be a problem.

Comment: @KavonFarvardin: Yes. I believe it is not possible to do this by the standard. Usually, when you convert a type into a `std::function<X(Y)>`, it plugs your given type into the constructor to see if it "works", by trial and error. We happen to know that the secret to what "works" is that the type to the `operator()` method on the object matches the parameter of `std::function`, but that is not possible to tell from looking at the type, and I believe not possible to express in the language. For all it knows, there might be many type parameters that will "work".